# Cant debug using RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

When I start the debug for development I get this message:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

then, nothing happen, I wait for long time, and nothing happen, although database setting is correct

If I start the server with development with no debugging, it will start normally

Any idea ? where to check for this issue ?

```
EDIT
```

database.yml:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On Mac OS X with macports:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dcaclab_development
  pool: 5
  username: samir
  password: 123456

#  adapter: postgresql
#    encoding: unicode
#    database: jerry
#    pool: 5
#    username: tom
#    password: myPassword

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # The server defaults to notice.
  #min_messages: warning

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dcaclab_development
  pool: 5
  username: samir
  password: 123456



production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dcaclab_development
  pool: 5
  username: samir
  password: 123456
```

**EDIT 2**

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) 

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide --dispatcher-port 33169 --port 46779 -- /root/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development


Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:46779
```

Comment: show us your database.yml file. There is something wrong

Comment: but, my app is working normally without the debugger! any way, here is the settings above in the EDIT

Comment: Which version of RubyMine are you using and which version of the `ruby-debug` and `ruby-debug-ide` gems are installed?

Comment: RubyMine 4.5.1, please see EDIT 2 above, p.s: when I installed it at the root user, it worked fine .. and it used to work fine too with my sudo user, but, something went wrong, I don't know what happened ..